# Making a scriptable dynamic Distance Joint in Unity

Tags: unity

I have 2 2D RigidBodies that are connected together using a `Distance Joint 2D`...

I update the distance of said `Distance Joint 2D` (using a script) expecting the distance between the two RigidBodies to change, but nothing actually happens.

I'm guessing this is to do with the Physics engine not updating the positions of the RigidBodies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to do the same thing. My problem was solved by applying a force of size 0 to some body. My uneducated guess: just changing joint distances is not sufficient for the physics engine to update.

Try this on a rigidbody:

```
    body.AddForce (new Vector2 (0, 0), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Might revive my 4 month dead project thanks to you :P

Comment: No problem. Good luck!